# Shuffle values in list<Integer> in java

Tags: java

I am trying to shuffle values in a list of Integers in java.I tried using the following method but its not getting shuffled.

```
List<Integer> dataList1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
//adding values to list
Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(dataList1));
```

Where am I going wrong??

Comment: Then what should be used to shuffle?I am just trying out

Comment: ⚠ `Arrays.asList(someList)` gives you a list with 1 element that is the first list (so, a singleton list of a list)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`shuffle` shuffles the list you pass it. Currently the list you pass is not `dataList1` but a new list created from the `dataLits1`. To that new list you are holding no reference, so the moment you finish with the shuffling you have no access anymore to that newly created list with the shuffled results.

Instead what you should do is:

```
Collections.shuffle(dataList1);
```

Comment: This is correct, but misses the point that the list which is being shuffled is a singleton list, where that element is `dataList1`. You can't shuffle one thing and expect it to be different ;) So, even if you did hold onto the reference to the list, it wouldn't do what is intended.